# Can I do hand free orgasm or ejaculation during ramadan fast?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Hand free orgasm,  I mean no touching private parts, just with wet day dreams, kind of intentionally. Can it be done? Will it break my fast?

Answer (score 1):

If you intentionally ejaculate, yes it will break your fast.

I don’t understand why you’d want to do such a thing since you won’t even end up feeling any pleasure?

And I’m not too sure if it’s possible to intentionally make yourself have a wet dream.

Comment: I meant sexual fantacies, wet daydreams, those are intentional.

Comment: @Esme As long as you don’t ejaculate. However, it will cause you to release Cowper’s fluid. It’s also not recommended to dream of such things Ramadan or not, but if it does happen, your fast won’t be broken but it will cause you to get aroused.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid these things as much as possible, Allah sees you wherever you hide, and knows your intentions better than anyone.